# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IBM_JAVA error while running hadoop 2.2.0 in eclipse

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IBM_JAVA
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getOSLoginModuleName(UserGroupInformation.java:303)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:348)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2590)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache$Key.<init>(FileSystem.java:2582)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2448)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:166)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:653)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.addInputPath(FileInputFormat.java:408)
at MaxTemperature.main(MaxTemperature.java:25)
```

I am getting the above error while trying to run a hadoop madp-reduce program in eclipse under Windows-7

JDK Version :

```
java version "1.7.0_25"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_25-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.25-b01, mixed mode)
```

same type of question is already asked here :

[the IBM_JAVA error for running jobs in Hadoop 2.2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22278620/the-ibm-java-error-for-running-jobs-in-hadoop-2-2-0)
but no one has answered.

IBM_JAVA is not a variable used in the code.

I am new to hadoop, i dont know what i am missing. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

The cause is that your java dependancies are not complete, you have lost the jar package hadoop-auth-2.2.0.jar or its newer version

Answer (score 0):

Like user3762708 said, you are missing the hadoop-auth package, add that to your classpath.

Additionally: If the problem persists, remove hadoop-core from your classpath. It will conflict with hadoop-auth.

Answer (score 0):

**Add**
    Hadoop-auth 2.6
    Hadoop-core 1.2.1

Hadoop-auth 2.6 --> org.apache.hadoop.util.PlatformName.class has IBM_JAVA (So add the Jar)

org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation is present in Hadoop-common and it does not have IBM_JAVA
Then **Remove**
 Hadoop-common x.x if already added