# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IBM_JAVA

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, flume

I see many references to this question and I have followed posted in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24105852/java-lang-nosuchfielderror-ibm-java-for-a-simple-hbase-java-client-in-eclipse)

I am using Hadoop 2.4.1 and Flume 1.5.0.1. My flume-env.sh configuration is as below

```
FLUME_CLASSPATH="/var/lib/apache-flume-ng:lib/hadoop-core-1.2.0.jar:lib/hadoop-auth-2.4.1.jar:lib/hadoop-yarn-api-2.4.1.jar:lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.4.1.jar:lib/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core-2.4.1.jar:lib/hadoop-common-2.4.1.jar:lib/hadoop-annotations-2.4.1.jar"
```

with these jars I have added one more jar that is commons-configuration-1.6.jar available in lib of Flume. I am new to Flume and Hadoop.

Complete trace is as follows:

```
ERROR [conf-file-poller-0] (org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run:149)  - Unhandled error
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: IBM_JAVA
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.getOSLoginModuleName(UserGroupInformation.java:337)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.<clinit>(UserGroupInformation.java:382)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.authenticate(HDFSEventSink.java:553)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.hdfs.HDFSEventSink.configure(HDFSEventSink.java:272)
    at org.apache.flume.conf.Configurables.configure(Configurables.java:41)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadSinks(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:418)
    at org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:103)
    at org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally i found an answer for this.

1. Copy the PlatformName class from hadoop-auth and custom compile it locally.

   package org.apache.hadoop.util;

   public class PlatformName {

   ```
       private static final String platformName = System.getProperty("os.name") + "-" + System.getProperty("os.arch") + "-" + System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model");

       public static final String JAVA_VENDOR_NAME = System.getProperty("java.vendor");

       public static final boolean IBM_JAVA = JAVA_VENDOR_NAME.contains("IBM");

       public static String getPlatformName() {
           return platformName;
       }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.out.println(platformName);
       }
   }
   ```
2. Copy paste the class file in your hadoop-core. You should be up and running.

thanks to all

Comment: Solution is to add all the jars found in $HADOOP_HOME/share/ all libraries. By that you dont have to add any custom code at all

Answer (score 6):

The problem is caused by missing or conflicting dependencies:

1. Add hadoop-auth to your classpath
2. If the problem still arises, remove hadoop-core from your classpath. It is conflicting with hadoop-auth.

This will solve the problem.

Comment: yes, this solved my problem. I had to add hadoop-auth and remove hadoop-core.